# Retrofit2 Post body as Json

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I was updating Retrofit to use **Retrofit2** and I already managed to a lot of things GET, POST, PUT...

But i had a request that i have to send a whole JSON I managed to do it in Retrofit 1.9 but in Retrofit2 there is no support for it.

```
import retrofit.mime.TypedString;

public class TypedJsonString extends TypedString {
    public TypedJsonString(String body) {
        super(body);
    }

    @Override
    public String mimeType() {
        return "application/json";
    }
}
```

How to make it **retrofit2** ?

Answer (score 7):

You can literally just force the Header to be `application/json` (as you've done) and send it as a string...

..

```
Call call = myService.postSomething(
    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), jsonObject.toString()));
call.enqueue(...)
```

Then..

```
interface MyService {
    @GET("/someEndpoint/")
    Call<ResponseBody> postSomething(@Body RequestBody params);
}
```

Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you sure, you can use @ Body as part of a post request under retrofit2? I'm getting a pretty Exception "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @ Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #2)"

Comment: Yes, absolutely. The code I gave is from my project which is working. But, if you're using the `@Multipart` annotation, you must use the `@Part` annotation as well as MultipartBody.Part as the param, or if you're using a `@FormUrlEncoded`, you have to use the `@Field` annotation.

Comment: No, I'm using neither @ Multipart nor @ Part tags. I'm using @body and RequestBody . Kind Regards

Comment: Regardless, I am 100% positive you can do this. Make a new post with a question if you're having difficulties.

Comment: `@Body` also works nicely with Retrofit 1.9, if the parameter you're passing implements `TypedOutput` and overrides `String mimeType()`.

Answer (score 5):

I Fixed the problem with the next code

```
public interface LeadApi {
    @Headers( "Content-Type: application/json" )
    @POST("route")
    Call<JsonElement> add(@Body JsonObject body);
}
```

Note the difference I'm Using Gson JsonObject. And in the creation of the adapter i use a GSON converter.

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class APIAdapter {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "BaseURL";

    private static Retrofit restAdapter;
    private static APIAdapter instance;

    protected APIAdapter() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
        restAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).client(client).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    }

    public static APIAdapter getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new APIAdapter();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public Object createService(Class className) {
        return restAdapter.create(className);
    }

}
```

Take care to have the same version of Retrofit and it's coverter. It lead to errors!

Comment: don't understand why it got downvoted, but this defn works